# Can I safely mutate an array I am iterating over, if it returns to its original state after each iteration?

Tags: java, loops

I am writing a minimax algorithm for a game in Java, and, for speed purposes, mutating the game state as I recursively work through the decision tree. However, this involves modifying the list of moves I am iterating over.

```
public int minimax(int currentDepth) {
    if (currentDepth == depth || board.legalMoves.isEmpty()) {
        int eval = board.eval();
        board.takeBack(1);
        return eval;
    }
    int x = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (Tuple move : board.legalMoves) {
        board.move(move);
        x = max(x, -1*minimax(currentDepth+1));
        board.takeBack(1);
    }
    return x
}
```

The `board.move()` method mutates the `ArrayList legalMoves`, but `takeBack(1)` brings it back to its original state. Could this cause any problems?

Comment: Just hope you don't have more than one thread accessing the tree...

Comment: Why are you using a loop here? It will *never* iterate beyond the initial element because you return from the method.

Comment: The aforementioned `return` also renders the call to `board.takeBack(1)` as dead code, which somewhat kills the purpose of the question.

Comment: Haha, that shouldn't be a return statement; I'll fix it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word, yes.

You don't specify the type of `board.legalMoves`. You say that it's array, but it can't be, since you're calling `isEmpty()` on it. I therefore suspect that you mean `ArrayList`. If that's the case, the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is pretty clear:

> The iterators returned by this class's `iterator` and `listIterator` methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own `remove` or `add` methods, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

I see two ways around this:

1) **Avoid structural modifications.** In other words, it's OK to change the *values* of the elements, but it's not OK to add/remove elements.

2) **Iterate over the `ArrayList` using indices:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < board.legalMoves.size(); i++) {
    Tuple move = board.get(i);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Argh, I was afraid of this. Is there a way around this? I would prefer not to have to clone the array list for every iteration of the algorithm; I think that would slow it down significantly...

Comment: It depends on the exact modifications that you need to do. If you don't modify the list *structurally*, you should be OK (see the Javadoc for an explanation of what constitutes a structural modification).

Comment: @mavix I guess it depends on how you're specifically changing `legalMoves` in `board.move(move)`.

Comment: I've added another suggestion to my answer.

Comment: board.move() does indeed change the structure of the ArrayList. I think your idea of accessing it by index should work! I'll find out tomorrow, though, it's almost 4am

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but it's dangerous. I suggest to move the minmax algorithm to a new class and pass the data to analyze into the constructor.

Now, you can copy the data **once** in the constructor and the methods can operate on the copy. The algorithm can now modify the data in any way it wishes, it won't influence other parts of the game or other threads. Also, if you have any problems, they must come from the code in one class.

The general goal is to give each modifying part of the code a copy of the data it needs to cut dependencies which can cause trouble.